# What does Azure Recovery Services actually backup?

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have some questions about Azure recovery services that I can't find on the azure website:

1. If I have a windows VM with SQL and IIS installed and a network drive (azure file service account). What will actually be backuped? Do all files from all drives get backuped?
2. Is it possible to download the backuped files? or at least see where they live?
3. Can you set your own storage account for Azure recovery services?
4. Does Site Replication have a purpose for Azure VM's, or only for on-premise servers. I can't really figure out what site replication does.
5. How do I delete a backup after I created it, the delete-backup button always seems disabled.
6. What happens when I do a restore, does it basically just write back a copy of the VHD to my storage around and reboots the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a windows VM with SQL and IIS installed and a network drive
>   (azure file service account). What will actually be backuped? Do all
>   files from all drives get backuped?

Base on my experience, Azure Recovery service will backup your data disks(no more than 16), storage, and system environments of VMs at the scheduled time. And backup entension to take a point to time snapshot and transfer this data into backup vault. Please refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-introduction/) and the picture:
[image]

> Is it possible to download the backuped files? or at least see where they live?

You can check them status[Backup Item] on Azure portal, such as this picture:

[image]

> Can you set your own storage account for Azure recovery services?

No. So far, the backup items is store into storage. But the data is encrypted.
see this document comment[post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-configure-vault/).

> Does Site Replication have a purpose for Azure VM's, or only for
>   on-premise servers. I can't really figure out what site replication
>   does.
>
> How do I delete a backup after I created it, the delete-backup
>   button always seems disabled.

From your description, I think you may need to understanding the concept of Azure Site Recovery and Azure back up service, please refer to these document for more details:[site-recovery-overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-overview/) and [azure backup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup/#what-is-azure-backup). Then you can follow the document to manage your backup items.Also, you can delete it.

> What happens when I do a restore, does it basically just write back a
>   copy of the VHD to my storage around and reboots the VM?

The data is retrieved from the Azure Recovery Services vault.
Please refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-restore-windows-server-classic/) about how to restore the backup item into the same service and other servers.

Comment: Any questions, please let me know. :)